# How to connect my Access Database using Java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, connection

I have the following code

```
import java.sql.*;
public class UserLogin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Load MS accces driver class
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

            // C:\\databaseFileName.accdb" - location of your database 
            String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,    *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "C:\\AGENDAS\\Agenda.accdb";

            // specify url, username, pasword - make sure these are valid 
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "Java2016", "Java2016");

            System.out.println("Connection Succesfull");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

and it throws the next error

> Got an exception!
>
> ```
> sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
> ```

How can I make the connection?

Comment: Please dump the exception with the stacktrace (`e.printStackTrace()`)

Comment: Well iirc, shouldn't you define a ODBC connection in windows and then address it by name? I have never seen this "on demand definition" of the driver, doesn't mean anything, though :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you already use JDK8, I suppose the exception you get is a "class not found" exception. But since you did not post the full stack trace, it is not sure - yet, the class name in the output is a strong pointer in that direction.

Please check the source of your initialization of the JDBC URL, I would be interested. In the driver docs, this style is not listed:

> 9.3.5     What Is the JDBC URL Supported by the Bridge? The Bridge driver uses the odbc subprotocol. URLs for this subprotocol are of the
>   form:
>
> ```
> jdbc:odbc:<data-source-name>[<attribute-name>=<attribute-value>]*
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> jdbc:odbc:sybase
> jdbc:odbc:mydb;UID=me;PWD=secret
> jdbc:odbc:ora123;Cachesize=300
> ```

http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/904preview/jdk14doc/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html

Additionally, this is what I found on the state of the ODBC driver.

> Status of the JDBC-ODBC Bridge
>
> The JDBC-ODBC Bridge should be considered a transitional solution; it
>   will be removed in JDK 8.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html

Since you are currently starting the project, it seems wise not to use the JDBC-ODBC bridge. Instead use JDK8 and find a solution involving SQL.Server express edition...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Access i suggest using `UCanAccess` which is an open-source Java `JDBC` driver implementation that allows java developers and jdbc client programs to read/write Microsoft Access database (`.mdb` and `.accdb` files).
I think it's simpler and has more support than the traditional `JDBC-ODBC` bridge.

After downloading the `UCanAccess` driver, this is how you can set up your connection :

```
    private Connection con ;

    private Statement stmt;


    public void connect ( String path ){

        try {
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

            this.con = DriverManager.getConnection(path, "", "");

            this.stmt = con.createStatement();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.err.println("classnotfoundException: " + e.getMessage());


        }
    }
```